# c# how to get element width

Tags: c#, width, element

Is there a way that I can do the equivilant of jQuery's

```
var myElementWidth = $('.class').width;
```

in c# and store it as a variable to use later.

Any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: are you aware of the fact that this will happen server side? Do you want to get the Width of a specific server control like a TextBox?

Comment: What kind of situation are you in? Are you generating the webpage using ASP.NET? Are you downloading it from web? Showing it in a webbrowser control?

Comment: To my knowledge, that's not valid C# in an ASP.NET page: I can _only_ relate this to jQuery given the selector, I may be mistaken, but...

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment If the element size is fixed server-side then you can access it :-) (a width css attribute in pixels for example) But I don't think this is what the OP wanted :-)

Comment: @xanatos actually, your suggestion of a fixed width css attribute would work as the parent element has a class which I know the size of. Any ideas how I could get the class of the elements parent?

Comment: In the end I used HTMLAgilityPack to look up the class name and then was able to do a check to assign a value to a width variable.

Answer (score 0):

As some comments are pointing, if positioning and sizing happens in client-side, C#, server-side code will never know about actual dimension and location of some given element.

But if this *width* is very important for your Web application, maybe you can set this value just after client renders the page with some asynchronous operation.

I'd argue that one of simpler ways of doing it would be implementing `ICallbackHandler` interface:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx

This will allow you to take some value from the client-side and save it in the server without postbacks, so you can store it in some session-state item.